# ¿Cómo puedo ver de forma ordenada el numero de veces que se repite un valor a lo largo de una columna en un DataFrame y relacionarlo con otra columna?

Tags: python, pandas, bucle-for, csv, data

En primer lugar me gustaría disculparme de antemano por si no estoy utilizando stackoverflow de la forma más óptima pero soy nuevo con Python y también en stackoverflow.

Partiendo de un dataframe (he estado buscando y creo que no puedo adjuntar el dataframe aquí) con 11 columnas y 841 filas. Una de las columnas son las edades (desde 0 hasta 80, algunos valores se repiten y también hay décimales como 0.8) y otra es la supervivencia que son booleanos siendo 1 que ha sobrevivido.

Teniendo en cuenta esto, me gustaría ver que edades son las que más han sobrevivido. Es decir, quiero que recorra la columna de edades y que me vaya contando las que se repitan, y que me devuelva aquellas que se hayan repetido más veces con la condicion de que en la columna de survivor tenga un 1.

He intentado algo así:

```
import pandas as pd
import math 

archivo = pd.read_csv('train.csv')

obj = {}

for registro in archivo.loc[archivo['Survived'] == 1].groupby(['Age']):
    ageRounded = math.floor(registro[0])
    if obj.exists(ageRounded):
        obj[ageRounded] = obj[ageRounded] + 1
    else:
        obj[ageRounded] = 1
```

Intenté crear una lista vacia que es obj, y luego hacer un bucle for donde survived sea igual a 1 para que solo cuente con aquellos que han sobrevivido y lo agrupe con la columna edad. Luego redondee los valores para que quedaran todos enteros y luego quería que buscara en la columna ages y si existía en la lista, le sumaba uno, si no existía pues el valor era 1. Pero me falta algo y es que no se si esto está bien y además me he quedado atascado aquí y no se como continuar.

El output tiene que ser un df de 10 filas aproximadamente y que me ponga la edad y al lado el nº de veces que se ha repetido, por ejemplo:

```
edad  frecuencia/nº de repeticiones
58        7
45        5
66        3
21        2
```

Algo asi, ordenado de mayor a menor

Alguién podría echarme una mano?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los ciclos cuando usas `pandas` en general suelen ser ineficientes en comparación con las propias herramientas del paquete y conviene evitarlos por que incluso son innecesarios muchas veces. Lo que estás buscando en parte ya lo has logrado con el `group_by()` solo te resta contar los casos y ordenar los resultados:

```
result = archivo.loc[archivo['Survived'] == 1].groupby(['Age']).size().reset_index(name='count').sort_values(by=['count'], ascending=False)
```

---

Detalles:

- Con `size()` contamos los casos de cada grupo (Age).
- Con `reset_index(name='count')` nos aseguramos de retornar un `dataframe`
- Con `sort_values(by=['count'], ascending=False)` ordenamos por la frecuencia de mayor a menor